# Using sessions with mongoengine in Django 1.9

Tags: python, django, session, authentication, mongoengine

I need to use a noSQL database on Django, and among the list of unofficial mongo plugins, I decided to go with the legacy mongoengine 0.9 due to its good feedback and relatively comprehensive [documentation](https://mongoengine.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.0/django.html).

After days of trial and error, I'm able to connect to my mongoDB, create a custom user model (document), save user in DB, and even use Django's auth function like `authenticate()`, `set_password()`.

Problem arises when I'm trying to use `login(request,user)`. The line that crashes in that method includes:

1. `request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)`, given that the mongo user document doesn't have the attribute `pk` in `meta`. I'm able to get through this by changing it to `user.id` directly, setting the Mongo's default id as the `SESSION_KEY`.
2. `return get_user_model()._meta.pk.to_python(request.session[SESSION_KEY])` in `_get_user_session_key(request)`. Which throws a `ValidationError` that says `{{id}} must be an integer`. Dumping `get_user_model()` on shell returns a mongo_auth.MongoUser and its `_meta.pk` reads `(AutoField id)`, which explains why `to_python` expects an integer value.

Is there a mongoengine way to use Django's session actually? I've set `mongoengine.django.sessions` as Session Engine in my `settings.py`, but not sure if there's anything else I need to do with it.

At this point of handling mongoengine's errors, I'm actually feeling quite unconvinced for its stability with Django, is there any other better option I should consider?

Comment: What Django version are you using?

Comment: @PetarP it's in the question, Django 1.9

Comment: Let me get back to you whit an answer to that, but the point is that `mongoengine` is built for `django 1.5`.

Comment: @PetarP no wonder. I also see that they've discontinued the django support on the new version. I've just forked the repo hopefully to find a workaround. Thanks for helping though :)

Comment: No problem, vote up.

Answer (score 0):

`mongoengine` v0.9 is built for Django 1.5, and the Django support has been separated from the `mongoengine` repo as of v0.10.

This is where the current repo is for the support of Django 1.9: https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine. The plugin still requires testing but so far auth and session works well on my project.

Discussion on this topic will be continued on the repo's issue tracker. Feel free to join and contribute.

Comment: are you saying that installing django_mongoengine fixed the request.session[SESSION_KEY] integer problem?

Comment: Tough django_mongoengine solved the mising pk attribute from _meta, I am still getting the validation error, (your second error) in  get_user_model()._meta.pk.to_python(request.session[SESSION_KEY]) , saying that id must be integer.  You found a solution for this?

Comment: @SergiuZaharie both of the errors got fixed after switching to django-mongoengine for me. Did you inherit the default `User` model and override the `id` attribute?